# AngularJS + ASP.NET MVC: routing URLs without corresponding physical view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

**Context**
We have a web app using AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC. It aims to replicate a file-system structure through URLs, like this:

```
http://(site1)//rootFolder//NFolders//File
```

For *views* in Angular, we are using *stateProvider*, with different states associated to **existing** views in disk (.cshtml files).

The problem issues when we request a file or folder from the browser and we try to serve a *virtual view* that doesn't really exist. We have just been able to achieve it with a full postback and some hacks, making a complete reload on each file/folder request.

**Question**: Is there a way of achieving that in Angular? Other way, the request for different URLs which don't have either their corresponding physical view as a file or any state in stateProvider, handling them with Angular and customizing a specific view which would deal with disk routes requested by URL?

**RE-EDIT**
We will have:

- a fixed root view for the website: http://website
- several root projects with a name:

  - http://website/site1
  - http://website/site2
  - ....
  - http://website/siteN
- each site may have different files and folders accesible via the URL:

  - http://website/site1/folder1/folder2/.../foldern
  - http://website/site1/folder1/folder2/.../foldern/fileX

**RE-QUESTION**: is it possible to handle this "virtual" URLs without having a physical view behind for folders or files? Our idea is to have one unique view called *siteController* which would control all the sites, and paths to folders and files.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you define rootFolder/NFolders/File as parameters. Then you can have a html file as the view template to populate data from server.

Have a look at this link

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. But the problem with using parameters is that first part of the URL is variable: http://website/(site1/(rootFolder)//(NFolders)//File: site1, could be site2, siteN, etc. Please see my reedition on the question in order to have futher explanations on the structure we are using.